# a process can contains multiple processes inside it?

Tags: java, jvm

recently I have read the article：
http://www.journaldev.com/1016/java-thread-example-extending-thread-class-and-implementing-runnable-interface
article has some lines:

> A process is a self contained execution environment and it can be seen as a program or application. However a program itself contains multiple processes inside it. Java runtime environment runs as a single process which contains different classes and programs as processes.

the line "Java runtime environment runs as a single process which contains different classes and programs as processes." make me confuse.I know a process can't contains multiple processes,except threads.But what the line means?jvm is a single process and contains onther processes?right?
thanks everybody!

Comment: That quotation is using a non-standard (or at least wrong-jargon) meaning of the word "process".

Comment: I think what the article meant to say there is that a single process can contain multiple different *threads*, which would be correct.

Comment: You means the line should be changed to "Java runtime environment runs as a single process which contains different classes and programs as threads."?

Comment: There is precedent for actual processes within processes, albeit in other environments. C# / .Net support `AppDomain`s, which do boil down to one ore more .Net 'processes' within a single native process. Each C# static variable has a unique value per AppDomain; DLLs are loaded independently into each AppDomain, heap memory is not shared, etc.